# Python 3: How to find the most occured value in the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to make a program which when given a dict like this-

```
    sports_played={sam:baseball,john:tennis,dan:tennis,joe:cricket,drew:tennis,mark:baseball}
```

should return tennis i.e. the most played sport i.e. the most occured value in the dict.

Sorry in advance if there is something wrong in the question. This is my first question.

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction of not importing anything? That makes this sound like homework, which you should be trying for yourself.

Comment: This is a basic homework type of question. What have you done so far?

Comment: `print(max(eaters.values()))`

Comment: As it is, this question has low chances of being answered: the (single line of) code you provide is invalid Python code and you don't show any research effort on your part. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to fall in line with this website's guidelines for asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that `eaters` is meant to be a dictionary, then:

```
eaters={'chicken':5,'meat':7,'rice':3} 
max(eaters.values())
```

result:
7

In the real world you would not use use a loop to achieve this.

To see what is available to you within `eaters`

```
dir(eaters)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']

eaters.keys()
['chicken', 'rice', 'meat']
eaters.values()
[5, 3, 7]
```

etc

The loop version:

```
x=0
for i in eaters.values():
    if i > x:
        x = i
print i
7
```

Comment: Before answering can you just read the comments above? This guys is asking you for a solution for his homework.

Comment: I see it as a mental exercise. If you pound dirt all day, mental exercise keeps the brain clean.

Comment: No because the site policy says so

Comment: Oh my... You really think you can compare that person's question to this? Do you not see how that phrased it and told us what he tired and why it did not work? He did not ask for an answer directly without him trying something himself. This person has not tried and is expecting someone to throw an answer to them. Understand the difference :)

Comment: yes because I did flag it but I still answered because the person did try at least

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `key` of the maximum element, i.e., `meat`, you can use the following code:

```
>>> list(eaters.keys())[list(eaters.values()).index(max(eaters.values()))]
>>> 'meat'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at `dir(dict)` you'll see an interesting method ready to use inside the `dict class/object` which is `dict.get()`.

So, if you type `help(dict.get)` in your python interpreter you'll get:

> Help on method_descriptor:
>
> get(...)
>       D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.

So, basicly `dict.get()` will look if a key is present in a dict and set it to `d` value (default is `None`).

So, we can do something like this:

```
eaters = {'chicken': 5, 'meat': 5, 'rice': 3}

counts = {}
for k in eaters.values():
    # If we find the k key in counts we add 1
    # If not set the count to 1
    counts[k] = counts.get(k, 0) + 1

print(counts)

>>> {3: 1, 5: 2}
```

So, we have a dict in which we count how many occurence of each value of eaters's dict.

Finally, to get the maximum of occurence of the `eaters` dict values we can do:

```
# get_max: temporar variable in which we stock the max
# val = will stock the key with the max value in counts dict
get_max, val = 0, 0
for k, v in counts.items():
    if v > get_max:
        get_max = v
        val = k
print(k)

>>> 5
```